# How to skip Airflow SparkSubmitOperator task based on exit code that my Spark programm returns?

Tags: apache-spark, airflow, spark-submit

My Spark submit application is doing some query and returning different exit code depends on the dataset state.

**Is it possible to skip downstream tasks right after my spark-submit operator?** I am thinking about `skip_exit_code` feature of BashOperator, which is surprisingly missing in all other operators.

```py
def spark_job(task_id: str, cfg: ArgList, main_class: str, dag: DAG) -> BaseOperator:
    copy_args = cfg.to_arg_list()

    return SparkSubmitOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        conn_id='spark_default',
        java_class=main_class,
        application=SPARK_JOBS_JAR,
        application_args=copy_args,
        total_executor_cores='2',
        executor_cores='1',
        executor_memory='1g',
        num_executors='1',
        name=task_id,
        verbose=False,
        driver_memory='1g',
        dag=dag
    )
cfg = CheckDataCfg(...)
check_data_task = spark_job('check-data', cfg, 'etljobs.spark.CheckDataRecieved', dag)

check_data_task >> '<my next task which I need to skip sometimes>'
```

**UPDATE:**
Current `SparkSubmitHook` implementation does throw an exception if `returncode` is not 0. So there are only two workarounds which I found later:

1. Create custom `SparkSubmitHook` and `SparkSubmitOperator` classes to ignore user-defined non-zero exit codes in way that either `AirflowSkipException` exception is going to be thrown or return code value will be pushed to XCom for further use.
2. Use `BashOperator` instead. It already support skip_exit_code feature. You would need to construct all CLI Spark args manually in Python which is not a big deal.

Comment: Why not using `ShortCircurtOperator` that pulls last task returned value from Xcom and then decide if to continue to downstream tasks or not

Comment: is it possible to pull last task exit code from Xcom ?

Comment: what is the value that you care about? driver status?

Comment: My driver application exits with specific return/exit code. I am wondering how to use it to skip or not to skip downstream tasks.

Answer (score 1):

The `SparkSubmitHook` has [_spark_exit_code](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/866a601b76e219b3c043e1dbbc8fb22300866351/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py#L191) that can be used here. We can create a custom operator that inherits all `SparkSubmitOperator` functionality with addition of returning the `_spark_exit_code` value.

I didn't test it but I think the following code should work for you:

```
from airflow.providers.apache.spark.operators.spark_submit import SparkSubmitOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import ShortCircuitOperator

def shortcircuit_fn(**context):
    exit_code = context['ti'].xcom_pull(task_ids='check-data')
    if exit_code=='125': # Place the codes here
        return True
    return False


class MySparkSubmitOperator(SparkSubmitOperator):

    def execute(self, context):
        super().execute(context)
        return self._hook._spark_exit_code

with DAG(dag_id='spar',
         default_args=default_args,
         schedule_interval=None,
         ) as dag:
    spark_op = MySparkSubmitOperator(task_id='check-data',..., do_xcom_push=True)
    short_op = ShortCircuitOperator(task_id='short_circuit', python_callable=shortcircuit_fn)
    next_op = AnyOperator()
    spark_op >> short_op >> next_op
```

This is how it works:
`MySparkSubmitOperator` will push to xcom the value of `_spark_exit_code` then `ShortCircuitOperator` will verify it against the expected codes if the condition is met the workflow will continue if not it will mark all downstream tasks as skipped.

Comment: Nice solution, but it seems `_spark_exit_code` field is used only when Spark app is running in Kubernetes cluster mode. In my case, I am not running it in Kubernetes :-(

Comment: @AlexeyNovakov There is a special case for K8s but it should work for non k8s https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/866a601b76e219b3c043e1dbbc8fb22300866351/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py#L442:L452

Comment: I mean that spark_exit_code is initialized only in kubernetes case, otherwise its value  is None: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/866a601b76e219b3c043e1dbbc8fb22300866351/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py#L503

Comment: I'm not sure why it's like that but you can create a custom hook that saves the returncode https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/866a601b76e219b3c043e1dbbc8fb22300866351/airflow/providers/apache/spark/hooks/spark_submit.py#L438 and then utalize that. A PR to the open source to address it is also welcome :)

Comment: Exactly, that is what have I just done: my own custom hook with several lines added to handle skip_exit_code, similar to what BashOperator is doing.

Comment: so yeah there is no out of the box solution. You have to code it with the options presented.